# How can I generate a fake coverage report for a Typescript/angularjs project with an artificial 0% coverage value?

Tags: angularjs, code-coverage, karma-coverage

I'm dealing with some legacy code that is being ported to newer frameworks. We're not going to bother to start unit testing the legacy code, because as we port it we also revise the business specification.

However, for the sake of statistical accuracy, I would like to include the 0% coverage that we have in our legacy code into our full coverage report (that includes other non-legacy modules using different languages and frameworks).

Given that this is an angularjs project and due to complications given by the architecture (usage of requirejs, global variable, being split into multiple apps) I have already given up setting an actual Karma test environment, my question is:

**what is the least painful way to generate a fake coverage report from the existing code that simply marks every line as not covered, yielding a 0% coverage report?**

I need something in a standard format (lcov?) that can be uploaded to coverage report websites like codacy/codecov/codeclimate etc.

Comment: in codacy for example you can ignore files as you would do with .gitignore, did you think about that? @Salvatore

Comment: @daviddd I actually want the opposite, i.e. to include files that are not covered. I just want the 0% number with the lines of code, for the metrics.